# How to make delay between two methods execution?

Tags: c#, async-await

I use async/await to make a delay between the method execution.

There is a code

```
public bool DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
{
    Task.Run(() => DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000));
    return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
}
```

```
public async void DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(int delay)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
        DoOpenProgressBarWindow();
    }));
    await Task.Delay(delay);
}
```

So, I would like to execute `DoPerformCommandOnClient` method then after 2 sec delay execute next line

```
return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
```

But instead this method `DoPerformCommandOnClient` executes without delay.

Then I tried to add `Thread.Sleep(2000)` between two lines

```
public bool DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
{
    DoOpenProgressBarWindow();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
}
```

But this approach stops my UI, I don't need to stop my UI.

So, the question is how to make a delay between two methods?

**EDIT**

now code looks like this

```
public bool DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
{
    Task.Run(() => DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000)).Wait();
    return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
}

public async void DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(int delay)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
        DoOpenProgressBarWindow();
    }));
    await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**EDIT2**

Now code looks like this

```
public async Task<bool> DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
        {
            await DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
        }

        public async Task<bool> DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(int delay)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                DoOpenProgressBarWindow();
            }));

            await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return true;
        }
```

**EDIT3**

```
public async Task<bool> DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
        {
            await DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
        }

        public async Task DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(int delay)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                DoOpenProgressBarWindow();
            }));

            await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

There is a way how I call this method

```
if (!m_MyManagerMainForm.DoPerformCommandOnClient(cmd1, true, sourcePath, "bmp", "ColorImageDone", "_M"))
            {
                RestoreGUIFromCalibration();
                return;
            }
```

but it doesn't work, it says that I can't implicitly convert `Task<bool> to bool`

Comment: Why do you need to run `DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay` in a different thread using `Task.Run`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Actually I don't, but I need to open this window then wait 2000 sec and then go ahead. Do you have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: `Task.Run` runs action on thread pool thread, you can make `DoPerformCommandOnClient` method an async and call `await Task.Delay(delay);` after `DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay`

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application of a WPF application? I suggest that you add the *winforms* or the *wpf* tag in your question, to get more focused answers.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Does it make sense in case of thread managing? Is there a difference between winform and wpf?

Comment: Winform applications, WPF applications, ASP.NET applications and Console applications have all different [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext)s installed. If you are asking for a general solution for any type of application, it's OK. Just be explicit that you are interested for a general solution, so that you are not getting suggestions about, for example, `ConfigureAwait(false)`, that are not generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

My bad, I didn't see the wait needs to happen **on UI thread**.
Now I updated my answer here, and call this not possible if the method is sync, and the UI should not freeze.

There's only one UI thread. And if it is blocked by sync method. The UI freezes for sure.

I recommend make `DoPerformCommandOnClient` async, so the task could be properly awaited, and the UI thread could be returned during the await:

```
public async Task<bool> DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000));
    return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
}
```

If the method has to be *sync*, then I recommend queuing a work to `ThreadPool`, , on the worker thread, wait 2 seconds and marshall the continuation back to UI thread.

Comment: But with this approach I need also change `performCommandOnClient` return type from bool to `Task<bool>` right?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You are using `Task.Delay` which is supposed to be used in an async context. You either could choose delay that does not require an async context, which is `Thread.Sleep`, or, you can use `ContinueWith` method like `Task.Run().ContinueWith(task=> GetLogic()... )`.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko also depends on your application type, you *can* use `Task.Run().Wait()`. It is only when you use that in WinForm app or ASP.Net (not Core) app, it can cause deadlocks.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Sorry I did not read the question clearly as I did not see the wait has to happen on UI thread. Now updated my answer. It is not possible to wait on the UI thread in a sync method and meanwhile do no block the UI.

Comment: Ok, but what should be a usage of `DoPerformCommandOnClient()`? Is it mean that I should now call this method like this `Task.Run(() => DoPerformCommandOnClied())`?

Comment: You don't need `Task.Run` to run an async method. `Task.Run` is a function which runs code on another thread as a new `Task`. If your method's return type is of a task, you can call your method like `await DoPerformCommandOnClient()`.

Comment: I edited my question and added a way how I call this method, but it doesn't work, it says that I can't implicitly convert `Task<bool> to bool`

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run` queues the action to run on the thread pool and returns immediately.

In your case, it is not necessary to call `Task.Run`. Make `DoPerformCommandOnClient` async and await `DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay`:

```cs
public async Task<bool> DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
{
    await DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000);
    return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
}
```

Don't call `Wait` (edit: this was suggested by another answer), the following will block your thread (same as calling `Thread.Sleep(2000)`):

```cs
public bool DoPerformCommandOnClient(string commandStr, bool isOnPath, string folderPath, string ext, string doneMessage, string excludeString)
{
    DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000).Wait();
    return GetLogic().PerformCommandOnClient(commandStr, isOnPath, folderPath, ext, doneMessage, excludeString);
}
```

As an aside, if you code isn't running in an "app context" (winforms or wpf) [call `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you await](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/), or you risk deadlocks. Also, [avoid `async void` for methods that aren't event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void):

```cs
public async Task DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(int delay)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
        DoOpenProgressBarWindow();
    }));

    await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: It not clear, about `await DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay(2000);`, because I can't just add word `await` to method signuture, I also need that return type `Taks<>` as well as `DoPerformCommandOnClient()` should return `Task<>`, so I am not sure that your answer on a right way, or maybe post another example, because according to this one it is not clear

Comment: Edited my question, take a look. Is it what you mean? Anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer. Are you able to change the signature of `DoPerformCommandOnClient`?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I understand if I change it to return `Task<bool>` it is means that `PerformCommandsOnCliend` method also should return `Task<bool>`, but I can't change the signature of `PerformCommandsOnCliend`. Or do you mean not this?

Comment: Nah dude `PerformCommandsOnClient` can return `bool`, the runtime wraps it in a `Task` for you. Consider perusing [Microsoft's examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types), they demonstrate this behaviour and more.

Comment: Edited my question, did you mean this implementation?

Comment: If yes, so now I can't call `DoPerformCommandOnClient` method as usual, now I need to call it with `Task.Run(() => DoPerformCommandOnClient());`, right?

Comment: My answer includes `DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay` right at the end. `DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay` only needs to return a `Task`, so its signature can just be `Task  DoOpenProgressBarWindowWithDelay` and in its body it doesn't need to return a `bool`.

Your `DoPerformCommandOnClient` is fine now.

Comment: I edited my question and added a way how I call this method, but it doesn't work, it says that I can't implicitly convert `Task<bool> to bool`

Comment: I strongly suggest converting all methods in your chain to async, all the way to your handler.